# Why does a count obtain an ExclusiveLock in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, performance, postgresql-performance

And what does this mean for other CRUD operations going against that table?

I have this query (actually I'm trying to write it 9 ways from Sunday to get it to return in less than an hour):

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT listing_id 
      FROM apps where subscription_id = 1298) AS temp
```

It churns and churns. When I look at a process list for the server, I find eight records. One for the table and six for the indexes. And apparently one for the statement itself.

It says `Locked Object` and the object name, and `AccessShareLock` next to the table and indexes. Then there is something that says `LockedTransaction` and next to it it says `ExclusiveLock`.

What does this ExclusiveLock mean, and will it keep other CRUD operations from running against that table?

Comment: Beside the point, but have you tried `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT listing_id) FROM apps... `

Comment: Yes. That one takes 1,818 seconds. The one above takes 1,788 seconds, and then one that I wrote that joins it to another table and includes a correlated subquery actually returned in 93 seconds: select count(*)
from listings
where subscription_id = 1298
  and listing_status = 'Active'
  and exists (select id
              from apps
              where apps.subscription_id = listings.subscription_id
                and apps.listing_id = listings.id)

Comment: An exclusive lock is typically taken by DDL statements. Maybe you forgot to commit an ALTER TABLE statement from a different session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every transaction is born owning an ExclusiveLock on itself.

For a read-only transaction, this will only block things like CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY.  For DML transactions, this lock will be used to block other transactions trying to update or delete the same row, or insert conflicting rows.